# Set Parent Template Defined Content to Output in Child Template

Tags: templating, include, extends, embed

I have a layout template, we'll call that **Template A** that is extended by another template, we'll call that **Template B** that includes another template, we'll call that **Template C** that includes another template lets call that **Template D**

So the visually it goes like so:

**-Template A**

**--Template B**

**---Template C**

**----Template D**

In Template C I define some content such as "**Hello World**" as well as a bunch of other content.

I do not want Template C to output the "**Hello World**" content but instead want **Template D** to decide where it is output as defined in **Template C**

I'm thinking that somewhere i might should use *embed* rather than **include** but i'm a bit hazy on exactly how to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE:** The content defined in **Template C** is defined *after* **Template C** includes **Template D** and also the content that is defined is not just a simple string as indicated above *"hello world"* but actually much more complex data.

**UPDATE:** Here is an example of the templates to help better understand the question.

**Template C:**

```
{% for block in entry.body.level(1) %}
  {% include 'Template D' %}
  {% if block.children is not empty %}
    {% block child %}
        {% for block in block.children %}
            {% include 'Template E' %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Where Template E is the *"Hello World"* content mentioned above.

**Template D:**

```
 {% if block.slide|length %}
     <div class="stuff">
         <ul class="somestuff">
             {% for background in block.slide %}
                 <li style="background-image:url({{ background.url() }})"></li>
             {% endfor %}
         </ul>
     </div>

     <section id="text-slider">
         <div class="container">
             {% block child %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
     </section>
 {% endif %}
```

And more code also after that endif. Where Block Child (in Template C) is the content to be defined and Block Child (in Template D) is where i want it output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of doing this for anybody interested is as I had guessed, using embed rather than include but also to setup a recursive macro like so in Template C:

```
{% macro recursiveBlock(block) %}
  {% import _self as self %}
  {% embed 'Template D' %}
      {% if block.children is not empty %}
          {% block child %}
              {% for block in block.children %}
                  {{ self.recursiveBlock(block) }}
              {% endfor %}
          {% endblock %}
      {% endif %}
  {% endembed %}
{% endmacro %}

{% from _self import recursiveBlock %}

{% for block in entry.body.level(1) %}
    {{ recursiveBlock(block) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Template D remains unchanged.

While Sam's answer was correct for a much simpler need, this is the way it had to be done (as far as I understand) for something more complex.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `include...with`, as specified in the Twig Docs [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html)

Example for your case:

```
{# in Template C #}
{% include 'template-d.twig' with {'foo':'Hello World'} %}
```

This should give Template D access to `foo`. Hope that helps!

Comment: Sam, i may have over simplified my question, the content in Template C is not just a simple string but actually a big bulk of content with includes of it's own.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry - it may be beneficial to post a bit more of the code, so users can get a general idea of what you're trying to accomplish. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!